# Outlook 365 Addin on Desktop

Tags: javascript, outlook, office365, outlook-web-addins

We have developed an Outlook Addin, which works just fine on Web, however the Desktop version has few issues. Of course the as usual The Microsft support is not helpful. So using this platform.

In add-in we want our cursor/caret to appear in the **To:** field right after loading the add-in. But it goes away and never appear until we click either inside the message body or any other text field.

I have checked the Outlook 365 Javascript API reference but not found anything relevant to caret.

Comment: To make it clear, is it after the add-in task pane loading on Outlook Windows Desktop?

Comment: Yes, it is after loading.

Comment: May I ask what the scenario is? Also, if I understand correctly, you want your taskpane addin to open and then the cursor to automatically fall into the To: recipients field?

Comment: Yes, you understood it correctly. There are two cases,
1> Addin is pinned
2> Addin not pinned

If it is pinned then right after opening the new message the cursor should appear in To:

If it is not Pinned then after opening it, the cursor must appear in To:

However, both of the above cases are not working and I had to click for cursor to appear.

Comment: What's the use case/scenario because of which you want the cursor specifically in the to field and clicking on it explicitly is an issue?

Comment: Actually, this Addin is to help our users to have their Signature (which is coming from our platform through API call) placed at the bottom, and as soon as the user enters the recipient email id, we update the redirect links (with encrypted recipient email) inside Signature so that we can backtrack the viewer of that link. 

As far as your second question is concerned, it is quite normal practice for most of the users to press Tab, tab to get to To field but in this case, the cursor vanishes and never appears.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT waiting for your response.

Comment: Understanding more about your scenario, is it correct to say that you actually don't really want a task pane for the addin?  The reason I ask is that Outlook puts the cursor in the task pane when it opens.  In your scenario, it sounds like you want your addin code (no UI needed) to listen to recipient changed events and update signature?

Comment: In our addin the task pane is a must, as it has some other functionalities like we have a drop down of videos from where we select the video name and size of the thumbnail to be inserted in email body. The dropdown is actually the textfield where we search and select the video name.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT any update?

Comment: Currently what you requested is not part of the native Windows client. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page (https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.